# PushWoosh and PhoneGap/Cordova 3.1 for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, pushwoosh

So I have an app I've built and works perfectly. I have all the provisioning done correctly and have it set to have push notifications. Now I am wanting to actually add the push notification feature.

I have my app added into my PushWoosh account and have configured it for iOS.

I referenced this page https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/ and completed everything.

At the bottom I don't understand the "Sample iOS push notification payload:" part. Maybe it's just a sample of what happens? But my biggest question is, where do I go from here? Is it ready for the app to be built, run, subscribe to push notifications, and test it out? After number 4 in that guide, there really isn't a next step to take.

Answer (score 0):

you dont even need step 4 its just show you where you get the notification from(step 1 line 5-14)

the "Sample iOS push notification payload:" its what the notification data you get will look like

right now your app is ready to receive notification, open it in your iphone and send a notification from pushwoosh.
you will get a alert with the message, the alert is coming from line 10(in the docs)

Comment: Gotcha! I ran the app from XCode to my phone plugged in to test it. I then sent a notification on PushWoosh but I never received anything. Also aren't I supposed to receive a permission notification to accept push notifications when the app opens? I also see that there still are no subscribers to the app in PushWoosh; there should be one which is me testing this out.

Comment: check your console you see the message from line 23 in step 1? or line 27?